# Translation software recommendation for offline use?

Tags: translation

I am using [Babylon](http://turkce.babylon.com/index.html) for a while and it is pretty fits often my needs. But I am wondering if exists any good alternatives to it. I specified my needs below:

### Key features

- **Broad dictionary support**: Beside individual works, big and professional dictionaries like Oxford, Redhouse etc. should be available.
- **Offline use** of dictionaries. I am not always have a internet connection. So, I need an offline product.
- **Quick ask, quick find**: Babylon can recognize most words appears on the screen with one-click. But as installed dictionary count increases, query performance slow down. Also its **GUI becomes heavier** in latest versions.

### Optional but plus

- **Text translation**: Ability to translate sentences.
- **Up to date**: Updates itself and dictionaries when connected to internet.

Comment: I hardly dig your automatic translation to English.
You want a dictionary that misappropriates OED and Redhouse to your hard drive, 

You want it to become slower over time

You will not use it if it ever translates a phrase, or attempts to update from internet....

Comment: What? We both talking about same thing?